# looping through specific files in python

Tags: python, file, loops, filenames

So I have a script where I loops through a set of files in a folder. After retrieving the list of files in that particular directory, how do I specify which files I want to use in the script?

```
target = './directory/'

for file in listdir(target):
```

Now I have several different files in the same folder.

- **kplr006933899**-2009131105131_**llc**.fits
- kplr006933899-2009131105131_**lpd-targ**.fits
- kplr006933899-2012151031540_**slc**.fits
- kplr006933899-2012151031540_**spd-targ**.fits

They all are part of the same group, which is denoted by "**kplr006933899**".
How can I specify parts of the strings as different variable in order to specify which files I want to loop through?

Like for example:

```
def function(name,types)
```

where you could write when called:

```
function(kplr006933899,[slc,llc])
```

Comment: Could you explain better? I mean, you want to group together all the files that start with `kplr` + some number and that contain specific other substrings or you simply want to filter the names that start with `kplr` and contain some substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. First way:

```
import fnmatch

def my_function(name, types):
    result = []
    for t in types:
        pattern = "{}*{}.fits".format(name, t)
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(listdir(target), pattern):
            result.append(filename)
    return result
```

You can call this function with: `my_function("kplr006933899", ["slc", "llc"])`. The [`fnmatch.filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) function performs the pattern matching with your pattern and the given filenames.

The second way is to use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
result = []
for t in types:
    result.extend(glob.glob("{}/{}*{}.fits".format(target, name, t)))
return result
```

Comment: @Bakuriu: Thanks, makes sense. I've added the `glob` solution as well.

Comment: Thank you simeon! This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "kplr" in  "kplr006933899-2009131105131_llc.fits"
True
>>> 
>>> "kplR" in  "kplr006933899-2009131105131_llc.fits"
False
>>>
```

Notice that you need to put quotes to denote a string `function("kplr006933899", [slc, llc])`, otherwise `kplr006933899` will be interpreted as a variable.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was just a typo. I was just looking into the fnmatch function, and I got this far:
'for file in os.listdir('./'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'kplr006933899*slc.fits'):'

Now I want to be able to specify the beginning of the string, and maybe a list of possible ends for the string, like slc, llc, so then it would only loop through the files with slc or llc at the end of the filename.